# How to cleanly save richtextbox content?

Tags: .net, save, alignment, richtextbox, rtf

I've got a problem : Creating a text editor, I save the richtextbox content in a rtf file. Also I'm ok, I test it, and, adding the text alignement option, I release that the alignement is not saved in the rtf file ! Also as I said, do you know how to save cleanly the text, i.e. saving all fonts properties as the text alignement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `File.WriteAllLines(filename, richTextBox1.Lines);`

Or this: `rtfTextBox.SaveFile(fileName);`

add `RichTextBoxStreamType` e.g.

```
rtfTextBox.SaveFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

or

```
rtfTextBox.SaveFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.TextTextOleObjs);
```

Comment: And .... the fact is not i can't save it , but the rtf format don't save the font properties

Comment: `OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        saved = True`

Comment: oops ,`OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` and `Richtextbox1.LoadFile(OpenFileDialog1.Filename)` (and `saved = True`)

Comment: But maybe i don't use the best solution to save it , maybe i have to save it using something like `Richtextbox1.SaveFile("C:\Users\me\here.rtf",VBconservefontproperties)`